# Script use Heap Memory of JVM or System Memory

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

For some background,
As per my knowledge, when we start a java application, JVM allocates a Heap space and a stack for the application. This heap is used to store all the objects created by the application.

My question is that if I call a Shell script from my java code, the memory that is used by script, will it be allocated from the JVM heap space or the system memory space will be used.

Answer (score 1):

The **system memory** will be used.

Java will invoke a `fork()` **system call which will duplicate the parent memory** (current JVM memory in use) to be able to run the child (the command you are trying to run).

In general, when you execute a process, you must first `fork()` and then `exec()`. Forking creates a child process by duplicating the current process. Then, you call `exec()` to change the “process image” to a new “process image”, essentially executing different code within the child process. This is how you create new processes to execute other programs / scripts.

See:

1. [Forking the JVM](http://bryanmarty.com/blog/2012/01/14/forking-jvm/)
2. [Shell processes from Java and the infamous OutOfMemory](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/09/shell-processes-from-java-and-infamous.html)